# Orientation of the unit interval

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, cobordism

Let the unit interval have postive orientation induced from the standard orientation of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ be equipped with orientation $+$. Why is $\{0\}$ then an in-boundary and $\{1\}$ an out-boundary? I don't understand how one defines a positive normal at the boundary of a 1-manifold like $[0,1]$? I do know that the tangent space of a one-point manifold is the trivial vector space $\{0\}$ with unique basis being the empty set, but I'm not able to put that to use here.

Thanks a lot in advance! All help appreciated.

Comment: Because everybody think of $[0,1]$ (and also similarly on $\mathbb{R}$) as the interval *from* $0$ *to* $1$, not the other way round.  So we use $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$, which flows into $[0,1]$ at $0$ and out of $[0,1]$ at $1$.

Comment: Isn't it more or less the same question  than https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3267481?